Understanding backed reconcile keys for Email Grouping in Outlook's "Show as Conversation" View
I'm seeking your assistance to better understand how the Outlook client groups emails when the "Show as conversation" view is enabled for the same email chain. I have reviewed the email properties and noted the following parameters:
Message-ID
References
Subject
Reply-to
However, I have observed that sometimes emails are grouped together even when these values don't match. Am I missing any additional parameters or considerations that might affect how Outlook groups these conversations?
Thanks in advance for your insights!
I tried to use below fields but it is partially working
Message-ID
References
Reply-to

Outlook groups conversations using several properties beyond Message-ID, References, and Reply-to. It also considers In-Reply-To headers and a hidden property called Conversation Index to track email relationships within a thread. If headers are missing or modified, Outlook may fall back on subject similarity and sender information to group emails. Make sure to check the Conversation Index and In-Reply-To fields for consistency. These additional factors should improve the accuracy of email grouping in conversation view.

Outlook uses PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX Extended MAPI property to group emails. See MSDN docs for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagconversationindex-canonical-property
